# Spring MVC: Getting NoSuchMethodError when adding an advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on Spring MVC project and I'm learning about AOP. So, I want to add logging aspect to my project.

LoggerAspect.java:

```
package com.mealdash.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggerAspect {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.mealdash.controllers.*.*(..))")
    private void forControllersPackage() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.mealdash.services.*.*(..))")
    private void forServicesPackage() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.mealdash.repositories.*.*(..))")
    private void forRepositoriesPackage() {
    }

    @Pointcut("forControllersPackage() || forServicesPackage() || forRepositoriesPackage()")
    private void forAppWorkFlow() {
    }

    @Before("forAppWorkFlow()")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        var methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        logger.info("--> Before: Calling method: " + methodName);
    }
}
```

Then, when I run my project I get this error:

```
22-Aug-2022 19:32:49.360 SEVERE [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cartController' defined in file [C:\Users\mo662\repos\MealDash\target\classes\com\mealdash\controllers\CartController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isLambdaClass(java.lang.Class)'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isLambdaClass(java.lang.Class)'
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(DefaultAopProxyFactory.java:64)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport.createAopProxy(ProxyCreatorSupport.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:480)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        ... 57 more
22-Aug-2022 19:32:49.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\mo662\.SmartTomcat\MealDash\MealDash\conf\Catalina\localhost\.xml] has finished in [9,546] ms
22-Aug-2022 19:32:49.381 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Aug-2022 19:32:49.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [9661] milliseconds
```

I reread my code and I discovered that when I comment the before advice method `beforeAdvice()` the project run and works successfully.
So, how can I love this problem?
Here my project files:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mealdash</groupId>
    <artifactId>MealDash</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MealDash Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MealDash</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mealdash"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
                class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
                            value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MealDash;integratedsecurity=true"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mealdash.entities"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
</beans>
```

CartController.java:

```
package com.mealdash.controllers;

import com.mealdash.interfaces.dao.CartDAO;
import com.mealdash.interfaces.dao.UserDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public class CartController {
    private final UserDAO userDAO;
    private final CartDAO cartDAO;

    @Autowired
    public CartController(UserDAO userDAO, CartDAO cartDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
        this.cartDAO = cartDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/addItem")
    public String addItemToCart(@RequestParam("itemId") int itemId, @RequestParam("menuId") int menuId) {
        var user = userDAO.getUserById(1);
        var cart = user.getCart();
        if (cart == null) {
            cart = cartDAO.createNewCart(1);
        }
        cartDAO.addItemToCart(cart.getId(), itemId);
        return "redirect:/menu/get?menuId=" + menuId;
    }
}
```

Compiled CartController:

// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

```
package com.mealdash.controllers;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping({"/cart"})
public class CartController {
  private final com.mealdash.interfaces.dao.UserDAO userDAO;
  private final com.mealdash.interfaces.dao.CartDAO cartDAO;

  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
  public CartController(com.mealdash.interfaces.dao.UserDAO userDAO, com.mealdash.interfaces.dao.CartDAO cartDAO) { /* compiled code */ }

  @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping({"/addItem"})
  public java.lang.String addItemToCart(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam("itemId") int itemId, @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam("menuId") int menuId) { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Comment: could you provide your class for CartController

Comment: I will, but it doesn't matter. when I comment the whole CartController class another controller throws the same error

Comment: Do you have the compiled .class?  The error is likely a code block that's injected on compile time so it would only be in the class at "\repos\MealDash\target\classes\com\mealdash\controllers\CartController.class"

Comment: Yes. Compiled CartController is existed.

Comment: Can you post that one too

Comment: Also your springframeworks in your pom are different versions from eachother and I think that of in the dispatcher-servlet. Try unifying the pom versions first and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Done! I added it to the question.

Comment: The different versions caused the problem. I unified them and the project works. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! putting it as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Springframeworks in your pom are different versions from each other and I think that of in the dispatcher-servlet. Try unifying the pom versions first and see if that fixes it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.22</version>
    </dependency>
```